# Is there a way to abort a ScheduledActivity of a SchedulableState?

Tags: corda

I would like to know if it is possible to cancel an execution of an ScheduledActivity.

Example:

A SchedulableState of type A is created, and the scheduledActivity will execute a flow that creates another SchedulableState of type A. It means that the app will always execute the flow determined in the activity and create another state of type A.

How can I abort the execution of the activity?
How can I identify if is there a ScheduledActivity waiting to be executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Corda 4.x, there is no API to cancel scheduled activities.

Instead, you'd have to connect to the node's database directly and drop the required rows from the node's `NODE_SCHEDULED_STATES` table.